# Using RDFLib create a Graph and keep it up & running

Tags: rdflib

New to RDFLib...

So far the RDFLib examples that I've seen

1. creates a Graph,
2. parse
3. either serialize or query or both

I wonder is there a way after creating a graph & parsing the data - keep it up and running ?

So that we can write separate python programs just to SPARQL query the existing graph.

Not sure how to persist the graph beyond the program execution.